# SQL Server : clustered index slow

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have 2 database tables:

1. `Message` table that contains gps message
2. `MessageData` that contains message sensors values

I join them to get sensor values between 2 dates.

The query returns results slowly with 99% of time seeking the clustered index.

How to improve this performance? Any advice on the index or the query side?

I run the following query for join: I filter with primary key > 3264353049 to prevent seek  dates with rows from last  years

```
SELECT 
    t.MessageId, t.DataSourceId, t.[Value],
    DataSource.SourceNameId, DataSource.Name
FROM 
    [MessageData] t
INNER JOIN 
    [Message] m ON t.MessageId = m.MessageId
LEFT JOIN
    DataSource ON t.DataSourceId = DataSource.DataSourceId
WHERE
    t.MessageId > 3264353049 
    AND m.ObjectId = @objId 
    AND m.GpsTime BETWEEN @dtFrom AND @dtTo 
    AND m.Valid = 1;
```

[image: Query plan time ?]

[image: query plan screen2]

I have these indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE [MessageData] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [AnalogData_PK] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([MessageId] ASC, [DataSourceId] ASC)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [MessageData_DataSourceId_IDX] 
ON [MessageData] ([DataSourceId] ASC)
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_gpstime_objectid] 
ON [Message] ([GpsTime] ASC)
INCLUDE ([MessageId], [ObjectId]) 
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [Message_Object_UK] 
ON [Message] ([ObjectId] ASC, [GpsTime] ASC, [MessageId] ASC)
GO
```

Message table data:

```
MessageId            ObjectId    VectorAngle VectorSpeed Altitude    GpsTime                        X                      Y                      VisibleSatelites
-------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ------------------------------ ---------------------- ---------------------- ----------------
9988600080           192         0           0           0           2017-07-19 00:03:20            0             0             0
9988600082           192         0           0           0           2017-07-19 00:08:20            0             0             0
9988600086           192         0           0           0           2017-07-19 00:13:20            0             0             0
9988600089           192         0           0           0           2017-07-19 00:18:20            0             0             0
9988600092           192         0           0           0           2017-07-19 00:23:20            0            0             0
```

and `MessageData` table data:

```
MessageId            DataSourceId Value                  SourceNameId Name
-------------------- ------------ ---------------------- ------------ ------------------------------
9988600080           6364         0                      1            Engine
9988600080           6365         0                      2            Digital Input Status 2
9988600080           325346       0                      179          DOUT 1
9988600080           325347       0                      180          DOUT 2
9988600080           334214       0                      69           Bettary
9988600082           6364         0                      1            Engine
9988600082           6365         0                      2            Digital Input Status 2
9988600082           325346       0                      179          DOUT 1
9988600082           325347       0                      180          DOUT 2
9988600082           334214       0                      69           Bettary
9988600086           6364         0                      1            Engine
9988600086           6365         0                      2            Digital Input Status 2
9988600086           325346       0                      179          DOUT 1
9988600086           325347       0                      180          DOUT 2
9988600086           334214       0                      69           Bettary
9988600089           6364         0                      1            Engine
9988600089           6365         0                      2            Digital Input Status 2
9988600089           325346       0                      179          DOUT 1
9988600089           325347       0                      180          DOUT 2
9988600089           334214       0                      69           Bettary
9988600092           6364         0                      1            Engine
9988600092           6365         0                      2            Digital Input Status 2
9988600092           325346       0                      179          DOUT 1
9988600092           325347       0                      180          DOUT 2
9988600092           334214       0                      69           Bettary
```

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: @SahanSerasinghe how to improve it , any advice index side , query join side ?

Comment: Your WHERE *probably* isn't doing what you're intending it to do. A WHERE is a filtering mechanism executing after JOINs. So you're *probably* not limiting how many records are grabbed. I say *probably* because the optimizer ultimately decides how to handle the query and may interpret it differently than is obvious.

Comment: @yanman1234 how to improve that ? because this table have a really large rows count

Comment: Moving parts of the `where` clause, e.g. `t.MessageId > 3264353049`, to the first `on` clause may alter the query optimizer's execution plan. There doesn't appear to be anything in the `where` clause the references `DataSource`, hence it could all be added to the first `on` clause.

Comment: Could you post the rest of the query plan?

Comment: As HABO pointed out, ONs typically occur during the JOINing process, so you're more likely to achieve what you want by making your WHERE an ON. Just be careful not to overly use ON as that could have an adverse effect.

Comment: @XingzhouLiu how to share full plan ?

Comment: I assume your statistics are totally out of date - you have an "Estimated number of rows" of 4.06, and an *Actual* Number of rows of way of 40'000 - that's never a good sign! Update all your statistics first, and run the query again

Comment: @marc_s how to update it ?

Comment: Search for "SQL Server update statistics" - should be **more than enough** documentation online to show you how to do it .....

Answer (score 0):

Well as mentioned in the comment I would definitely update my stats.  But after that I would look at this index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [Message_Object_UK] 
ON [Message] ([ObjectId] ASC, [GpsTime] ASC, [MessageId] ASC)
```

The query is doing that nasty Nested Loop Join because it has to seek in and find the records with the specific messageID that is has to pull out of EACH record in the Message table index.  Try changing it to:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [Message_Object_UK] 
ON [Message] ([MessageId] ASC, [ObjectId] ASC, [GpsTime] ASC )
```

This has a chance of getting you a hash or merge join

Comment: but MessageId is primary key here , ?  it will seek the primary key index in that case ?

Comment: From your script MessageID is the Primary Key of the MessageData table.  I have no idea what the PK is on your Message table.

Comment: no , MessageID Is primary key for Message , and for MessageData key is clustered index  [MessageId,DatasourceId]  and that index is take 99% of query time

Comment: Again, you may want to look at the script you posted as that information was not there.  Either way, the query is going to use the clustered index because you have included all three fields in the where or join clause.  As it is currently doing.  The problem currently is that they are sorted in different order so it has to do a nested loop join that is VERY expensive.  Have you updated your stats?  Have you tried to change the clustered index?